# Restrcit color to the slider position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have designed a slider question using JS as when the slider moves the postion to the left we will be displaying the red Color and the middle we will dispaly with yellow like the same for right we will show with green, but whenever the slider is moved it is displayed to the total length of slider. I would like to restrict the colour to the position of slider .

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.slider_control').slider({
        value:0,
        range : 'min',
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        step: 1,
        orientation: "horizontal",
        change: function(e,ui){
            var myid=$(this).parent().attr("id");
            refreshSwatch(myid);
            $(this).find("input").val(ui.value);
        },
        slide:function(e,ui){
            var myid=$(this).parent().attr("id");
            refreshSwatch(myid);
            $(this).find("input").val(ui.value);
        }
    });
});
function getTheColor(colorVal){
    var theColor = "";
    if(colorVal<50){
                myRed = 255;
                myGreen = parseInt(((colorVal*2)*255)/100);
          }
      else  {
                myRed = parseInt(((100-colorVal)*2)*255/100);
                myGreen = 255;
          }
      theColor = "rgb("+myRed+","+myGreen+",0)"; 
    return(theColor); 
}
function refreshSwatch(myid) {
    var coloredSlider = $("#"+myid).find(".slider_control").slider("value");
    console.log(coloredSlider);
    myColor = getTheColor(coloredSlider);
    //$(".slider_control.ui-slider-range").css("background-color",myColor);
    $("#"+myid).find(".slider_control.ui-widget-content").css("background-color",myColor);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" />

<style type="text/css">

    #custom-handle {
      width: 3em;
      height: 1.6em;
      top: 50%;
      margin-top: -.8em;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 1.6em;
    }

    #slider {
      background-color:#8c464f;
      filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=1,startColorstr=#8c464f, endColorstr=#828c46);
      background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(left, #8c464f 0%, #828c46 25%,#468c5f 100%);
      background-image:linear-gradient(left, #8c464f 0%, #828c46 25%,#468c5f 100%);
      background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left, #8c464f 0%, #828c46 25%,#468c5f 100%);
      background-image:-o-linear-gradient(left, #8c464f 0%, #828c46 25%,#468c5f 100%);
      background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(left, #8c464f 0%, #828c46 25%,#468c5f 100%);
      background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right bottom, color-stop(0%,#8c464f), color-stop(25%,#828c46),color-stop(100%,#468c5f));
    }

  .ui-widget-header{background-image:none;background-color:#FFFFFF;}
  .ui-widget-content { background: #FFCCCC; }


</style>

<title>color slider </title>

</head>

<body>
<div id="slider" class="slider ">
  <div id="custom-handle" class="ui-slider-handle"></div>
</div>

    <script>
    $( function() {

      var handle = $( "#custom-handle" );
      $( "#slider" ).slider({

          range: "max",
          step: 2,
          animate: 0,


        create: function() {
          handle.text( $( this ).slider( "value" ) );
        },
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
          handle.text( ui.value );
        }
      });


    } );

    </script>
```